# Woocommerce pedidos

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de guardar un array con información para cada tipo de pedido en woocommerce. He creado el formulario, pero no se porque cuando le doy a enviar, o me guarda siempre un último carácter en el array (negrita), o bien me mete en cada campo del formulario el mismo valor ... Seguro que es una bobada, pero no doy con ello.

wc-pending----->swc-processing----->swc-on-hold----->swc-completed----->swc-cancelled----->swc-refunded----->swc-failed----->s**string(1) "s"**

El código es:

```
if($active_tab == 'mapeo_estados'){

  settings_fields ('bridge_settings'); 

  $estadospedido_woo = wc_get_order_statuses();
  $estadospedido_remoto=get_option('arrayestadosmapeados');

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //Si llegamos a esta pestaña y es para guardar datos, actualizamos el array de los estados mapeados

    delete_option('arrayestadosmapeados');
    //var_dump($_POST); 
    foreach ($estadospedido_woo as $key => $val) {
      
        if(!empty($_POST[$key])){
          echo($key."----->".$_POST[$key]);
          $estadospedido_remoto[$key] = $_POST[$key];
        } 
    }
    var_dump($estadospedido_remoto);
    add_option('arrayestadosmapeados', $estadospedido_remoto);
  }  ?>
  <p>Vamos a proceder a mapear los estados de los pedidos desde la plataforma externa, con los propios de Woocommerce.</p>
  <form action='' method="post">
  <table><tr><td>Estado en WOO</td><td>Clave WOO</td><td>ID Remoto</td>
  <?php foreach($estadospedido_woo as $key => $estado){
        echo "<tr><td>".$estado."</td><td>$key</td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"".$key."\" name=\"".$key."\" value=\"".$estadospedido_remoto[$key]."\"></td></tr>";
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ya he encontrado el problema ... era porque no se estaba inicializando el array antes de rellenarlo ...

```
$estadospedido_remoto=[];
```